# Self = [super init]

Tags: objective-c

If self is able to store the base class instance then when we are returning the self, how it transformed to derived instance.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I think you're asking: suppose we have a base class Base and a subclass Derived. If `-[Derived init]` calls `-[Base init]` and `-[Base init]` returns a different instance, won't that different instance be an instance of `Base` and not `Derived` and thus inappropriate? For example, the new object won't have the instance variables that `Derived` might have added to the class.

The answer is that `Base` is not allowed to do that. If it replaces the original instance, it must do so in a manner that respects the dynamic type of that original instance.  For example, it might do something like:

```
// Re-allocate with 100 extra bytes
id newSelf = NSAllocateObject([self class], 100, [self zone]);
[self release];
self = newSelf;
// ... continue to initialize ...
return self;
```

Or, it might dynamically generate a new subclass of the original class and then allocate a new instance of that new class.

```
NSString* newClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@_DynamicSubclass", NSStringFromClass([self class])];
Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair([self class], [newClassName UTF8String], 0);
// ... further configure the new class, by adding instance variables or methods ...
objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
id newSelf = [newClass alloc];
[self release];
self = newSelf;
// ... continue to initialize ...
return self;
```

Whatever it does, it has to satisfy the constraint that the new instance is suitable to be used wherever the old instance was, based on its dynamic type.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a hidden method argument:

```
// this Objective-C
- (id) initWithString:(NSString*)str;

// gets implemented like this C function would be
- (objc_object*) Foo_initWithString(Foo* self, SEL _cmd, NSString* str);
```

It is a pointer to memory (allocated with `alloc`) that is already big enough to hold the most derived object. The most derived class calls super's `init`, which also calls its super's `init` and so each class in hierarchy gets its constructor called.

So, nothing is transformed — it is just a pointer to an already existing object, you can either return it (99.9% of the time) or substitute another object instead.

Note there is a second hidden argument, the selector `_cmd`, which in this case equals to `@selector(initWithString:)`. You can also use it if you need current method name e.g. for debug logging.

Comment: I agree with you that self is capable to hold the derived object. But my doubt is 
                                                                    If NSString * tempStr = @"Hello"; NSString* tempStr1 = tempStr;

In the above case tempStr1 and tempStr is pointing to same location. Similarly self is pointing to super instance, but how it got transformed to derived instance.

Comment: @user1421041 No doubt — it is. But are you trying to ask something?

Comment: Yes. How super instance is going to be derived instance?

Comment: @user1421041 They are laid out in memory in a way so they start at the same address. A pointer to the most derived object is also a pointer to all of its base classes — no transformation is needed.

Comment: Thank you, If you can let me know how they are laid out in memory it would be much helpful.

Comment: @user1421041 try this presentation http://algorithm.com.au/downloads/talks/objective-c-internals/objective-c-internals.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here super instance is not assigned to derived instance. `self = [super init];` is simply like telling the runtime system to look for the init method to the super class method selector table... inside super `-init` method, the `self` is like support for both super class and derived class. In objective c, incase of class inheritance.. only instance variables are duplicated.. methods are shared by all classes in hierarchy. If u override.. u should do `self = [super init]`; this will lead u to NSObject `-init` method. If we override `-init...` methods from super class, make sure that the super `-init...` is called first. This is what i understand. Thank you.