# When I have to use self = [super init]

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I call self=[super init]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956943/why-should-i-call-self-super-init)

I been reading a book of Objective C, and to create a class that contains other classes (composition) it uses the self = [super init]

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        engine = [Engine new];

        tires[0] = [Tire new];
        tires[1] = [Tire new];
        tires[2] = [Tire new];
        tires[3] = [Tire new];
    }

    return (self);

} // init
```

And when he is creating another classes he doesn't include this init method, i understand that it need to initialize the instance objects it will be using, but i don't understand why is he putting the self = [super init] and when a class needs this statement.

```
@interface Tire : NSObject
@end // Tire


@implementation Tire

- (NSString *) description
{
    return (@"I am a tire. I last a while");
} // description

@end // Tire
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the other classes where this method is not used? It will be easier to explain then.

Comment: like Tire class, it only needs the new message or alloc]init] to start, but why this class init method need self = [super init]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I call self=\[super init\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2956943/), [Why use self=\[super init\] instead of just \[super init\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10139765/), [Why to use \[super init\] in constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9283004/), [self=\[super init\] revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554249/), [self=\[super init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10779937/), [What does the assignment of self to \[super init\] do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5594139/)

Comment: @JoshCaswell possibly, but I think the question was really about the difference between alloc/init and new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` is a class method that simply tells a class to perform alloc / init on itself. It is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new). The code above could be rewritten as:

```
- (id) init 
{ 
    if (self = [super init]) { 
        engine = [[Engine alloc] init]; 

        tires[0] = [[Tire alloc] init]; 
        tires[1] = [[Tire alloc] init]; 
        tires[2] = [[Tire alloc] init]; 
        tires[3] = [[Tire alloc] init]; 
    } 

    return (self); 

}
```

And it would have exactly the same effect, but involves more typing.

Within the Engine and Tire classes, their init methods (if implemented) will be using `self = [super init]`. If your class does not do anything special in its `init` method, you don't need to implement one, but if you *do* implement one, you must use `self = [super init]` because you need the object to be created properly, and your superclass may be doing important work in its init method.

Comment: thanks man you're explanation was very clear, i really was confuse about this statement, but now i get it =)